omit command output on systemd-run
when running systemd-run --pty --same-dir --wait --service-type=exec I get all the command output in journal. While nice, it is not something I want/can afford all the time.
for example, if I want root to run ls as
systemd-run --user  --nice=+1 --same-dir --collect --service-type=exec --pty --wait --unit MYSYSRUND ls -la

how can I avoid the output of ls being on journal? metadata is fine.

Does this actually happen even with --pty being specified?

@u1686_grawity was correct on the suspicion posted on the question comment.
With --pty the outputs are not sent to the logs. I made a mistake in my tests and and assumed it logged output either way. My question above is wrong.
The solution then is to add --pty and deal with the output (e.g. >/dev/null) and all work as expected.
